# Use Pearson Correlation to Assess Nonlinear Association?

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have two datasets $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ and $\{y_1, y_2, ..., y_n\}$. Each pair $(x_i, y_i)$ represents two properties of a system.
Here is the visualization:

[image]

The Pearson's Correlation Coefficient of the two datasets is 0.66, which is not low.

I also sorted $\{y_1, y_2, ..., y_n\}$ and the corresponding elements in $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ are rearranged accordingly, such that the "partnership" of any pair $(x_i, y_i)$ remains. Here is the figure:

[image]

We can see that $\{y_1, y_2, ..., y_n\}$ follows a power law distribution and can also clearly observe the relationship between $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ and $\{y_1, y_2, ..., y_n\}$.

My question is: is Pearson's Correlation Coefficient suitable for describing the relationship between the two datasets in this case? Are there any other quantitative ways to describe it?

Answer (score 1):

Pearson's correlation $r$ measures the *linear* component of association.

Spearman's correlation uses ranks instead of the values. Roughly speaking,
it measures the degree to which the two variables rise (or fall) together,
regardless whether the relationship linear.

Here are fake data in which $y = x + e,$ where $e \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0, \sigma=4).$ Thus the relationship is basically linear, but with some noise.
Pearson's and Spearman's correlations are both about 0.97.

```
x = 1:50;  e = rnorm(50, 0, 4);  y = x+e
cor(x,y);  cor(x,y, meth="spear")
## 0.9706131  # Pearson
## 0.9732053  # Spearman
```

However, if we consider the nonlinear relationship between $x$ and $y^3,$
Pearson's correlation is only about 0.84, whereas Spearman's correlation
is unchanged.

```
cor(x,y^3); cor(x,y^3,meth="spear")
## 0.8389872  # Pearson
## 0.9732053  # Spearman
```

Here are plots of the two relationships.

[image]

You believe you have an exponential relationship in your data. That would be relatively farther from
linear than the cubic relationship illustrated here. Bottom line:
I think you should consider using Spearman's correlation.

You can read specific information about Spearman's correlation online or
in a basic statistics text. Briefly, it is Pearson's correlation of ranks.

```
rx = rank(x);  ry = rank(y);  cor(rx,ry)
## 0.9732053
```

Comment: What I am trying to find is the relationship between the red line and the blue line. The red line looks like growing exponentially, while the blue line also seems to have the same trend but with more noise. I am not trying to find the relationship between $y_{red}$ and $x$, but rather $y_{red}$ and $y_{blue}$. Do they maybe have a linear relationship?

Comment: Then you want to look at _goodness-of-fit tests_. Not correlation.  You could get a significantly positive correlation between the blue observations and _any_ increasing function. A 'not low' correlation is a different thing than saying the blue data are exponentially distributed. I do not think the 'fit' between the blue data and the red line is promising. That's one reason I showed a cubic curve in my example.

Comment: $y_{red}$ is actually a sample of a population which exhibits a power law distribution.
The value of $y_{red}$ and $y_{blue}$ are not dependent on $x$ ($x$ is simply the index of the samples). Can I still use goodness-of-fit tests in this case?

Comment: why not using log() and then pearson r?